# Why would a quantity like the 'Hubble contrast' be squared, then have its square root taken?

Tags: observational-astronomy, cosmology, observable-universe, dark-energy, hubble-constant

From Sabine Hossenfelder's recent video, [New Evidence AGAINST Standard Cosmology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JETGS64kTys):

[image]

And her [source](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/401/1/547/1008219)....

[image]

> Figure 2. The variation with increasing void radius of the variance of the Hubble parameter, the density contrast, the density parameter and the peculiar velocity for the CDM power-law and CHDM bump models, given the *WMAP5* and SDSS data (with 1σ limits).

I don't get why a graph would show a quantity that is squared, then immediately 'square-rooted' such as $\langle \delta^2_H \rangle^{1/2}, \langle \delta^2 \rangle^{1/2}, \langle \delta^2_{\Omega} \rangle^{1/2} \ \text{and} \ \langle v^2 \rangle^{1/2}$.

Also, the lowercase delta does stand for the Hubble constant difference or contrast, correct?

Comment: The plot she is showing averages over $\delta H$, not $H$, i.e. a fluctuation field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The brackets refer to the average, so $\left< x^2 \right>^{1/2}$ is the root-mean-square (RMS) of $x$.  That is the square root of the mean (or average) of the square of multiple $x$s.

The RMS average is useful when a quantity can be either negative or positive.  For instance, a sine or cosine wave has an average of zero over one cycle, but its RMS average is proportional to its amplitude:

$$\left< A\sin x \right> = 0, \quad\quad \left< (A\sin x)^2 \right>^{1/2} = \frac{A}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

Comment: what further advantage does it have over the average of the absolute values?

Comment: @njzk2 : You might benefit from reading about the [RMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square), learning, for instance, that it is related to the standard deviation of a (0-mean, or centered) sample.

Comment: Another example of where taking the square root of squared values, because of possible negative values is when calculating variance, in statistics.